# Firefox/Firebug not showing thrown error messages

Tags: javascript, firefox, ember.js, ember-data, firebug

I had an error in my code which caused an exception to be thrown. It did originate from creating an Error() object, but it was from [EmberError](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.3.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/error.js#L13).

Firefox and Firebug produce the same output:
[image]

While Chrome actually shows the thrown message:
[image]

Comment: For those interested, this has been discussed here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12876

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ember, the default error message logs the `stack` property of `Error()`.

In Firefox, that is just the stack trace.

However, in Chrome, `error.stack` is the error message prepended to the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it may be related to Firefox currently not implementing `Error.captureStackTrace()` or some other API allowing to output the original error message, but could also be that ember.debug.js is just not loaded in Firefox for some reason.

Maybe the [Ember Inspector extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ember-inspector/) can help here.

Comment: The Ember Inspector does not show error messages. I personally only use it for viewing the Data. I'll look into captureStackTrace, that's probably why.

Comment: Sebastian Zartner is right. Chrome has more powerful debug tools when it comes to debugging javascript.